# plot freezedetect and blackdetect graphs ffmpeg

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, anomaly-detection

I want to plot freezedetect and blackdetect responses from ffmpeg onto a graph. Is there any method to do it?

Example: A line graph with frames/ seconds in the x-axis, that will have a value 1 when no freeze or black screen, and 0 when it detects an anomaly.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more precise. Do you just want solely this graph or is it supposed to happen in parallel with some other video processing or OpenCV processing going on at the same time? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Real time graph update would be my end goal.  But for now, if the plotting can happen offline it should be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If, as implied by your tagging, you are already running OpenCV and doing video-processing, surely it is simple to do blackdetect and freezedetect yourself rather than somehow parse the output of `ffmpeg`?

Comment: You are right, Mark.  Am able to do blackdetect and freezedetect.  I get the start and end times in a text file.  All I want is to show these numbers in an UI, preferable over a line graph.

Comment: See gnuplot, I guess. Not exactly sure which step you need help with.